# the synchronized issue involving in multi-threaded application--java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

The following is an interview question comes from online:

Design a task dispatching system which includes a task queue and two functions.

(1) Function: triggerTask. This one is responsible for invoking all the tasks in the task queue.

(2) Function: addTask. before the triggerTask function is called, addTask adds task into the queue. After the triggerTask function is called, addTask just invokes the task.

The following is my answer:

```
class TriggerTask {
    Queue<Task> q;
    boolean triggered = false; 

    addTask(Task t) {
        if (triggered == true) {
            t.invoke();
        }
        else {
            q.offer(t);
       }
    }

    triggerTask() {
          triggered = true; 
          while (!q.isEmpty()） {
                q.poll().invoke();
          }
   }
```

The follow up question is what if you want your design running in multi-threaded situation? I kind of lost it. Is there any problem for the above code to run in the multi-threaded situation? If yes, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When Thread1 will call triggerTask(), the boolean variable triggered will get set to true, but Thread2 calling addTask() may read the value of triggered from cache memory, so it will not see its value as true. To avoid this, you need to declare triggered as volatile.